# Woocomerce custom redirection after checkout per category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to have 2 diferent thank you pages based on 2 categories after payment.

I can redirect to just 1 page if product is on category item and to another one if not.

But i can't split this for 2 diferent categories, i'm just new on php could be nice if someone could help me with this.

**My code:**

```
add_action( ‘template_redirect’, ‘wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase’ );

function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {

global $wp;

if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars[‘order-received’] ) ) {

$cat_in_cart = false;
$order_id = isset( $wp->query_vars[‘order-received’] ) ? intval( $wp->query_vars[‘order-received’] ) : 0;
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$product_categories = array( ‘mezcla-y-mastering-online’, ‘asesoria-personalizada’ );

foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
if( has_term( $product_categories, ‘product_cat’, $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
$cat_in_cart = true;
break;
}
}

if ( $cat_in_cart) {
if(in_array(«asesoria-personalizada», $product_categories)){
wp_redirect( «https://artchitectsproductions.com/gracias-compra-asesoria/»);
} elseif (in_array(«mezcla-y-mastering-online», $product_categories)){
wp_redirect(«https://artchitectsproductions.com/gracias-compra-mezcla-y-mastering-online/»);
}

} else {
wp_redirect(«https://artchitectsproductions.com/gracias-por-tu-compra/»);
}
exit;

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code using dedicated `template_redirect` hook and WordPress `has_term()` conditional function (to be used with product categories), will redirect customers after checkout to my account section when their order contain items from defined product categories:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'order_received_redirection_to_my_account' );
function order_received_redirection_to_my_account() {
    // Only on "Order received" page
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
        global $wp;

        // HERE below define your product categories in the array
        $categories = array('Tshirts', 'Hoodies', 'Glasses');

        $order = wc_get_order( absint($wp->query_vars['order-received']) ); // Get the Order Object
        $category_found = false;

        // Loop theough order items
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
            if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
                $category_found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if( $category_found ) {
            // My account redirection url
            $my_account_redirect_url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') );
            wp_redirect( $my_account_redirect_url );
            exit(); // Always exit
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in the function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive all product terms using `get_the_terms()` and then push them to an array. Try the below code.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );

function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {

    global $wp;

    if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {

        $cat_in_cart        = false;
        $order_id           = isset( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ? intval( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) : 0;
        $order              = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $product_categories = array();

        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){    
            $product_cat = get_the_terms( $item->get_product_id() , 'product_cat' );
            if( !empty( $product_cat ) ){
                foreach ( $product_cat as $cat ) {
                    $product_categories[] = $cat->slug;
                }
            }
        }

        if( !empty( $product_categories ) && in_array('asesoria-personalizada', $product_categories ) ){
            wp_redirect( 'https://artchitectsproductions.com/gracias-compra-asesoria/');
        } elseif ( !empty( $product_categories ) && in_array('mezcla-y-mastering-online', $product_categories ) ){
            wp_redirect('https://artchitectsproductions.com/gracias-compra-mezcla-y-mastering-online/');
        }else {
            wp_redirect('https://artchitectsproductions.com/gracias-por-tu-compra/');
        }

        exit;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol you nailed it dude! it works extremelly perfect!!! thank you a lot!

Comment: Nice solution...